# Android Wear Testing in Emulator with Android Phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I am stuck with Android Wear Testing in Emualtor and my Phone.

I have installed Android 6(API 23) Android Wear Intelx86 Atom System Image in SDK Manager.

Create Android Wear Round AVD with required configurations. Now my Android Wear AVD is started properly.

Now i installed Android Wear app in my Phone and followed below video and steps to pair my Android Wear with my Nexus 5 phone.
https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056630?hl=en

I got an acknowledgement saying "Paired" in my phone after enabling Bluetooth and sharing the pair Token. Soon after that the phone hangs at below screen and i am not able to proceed further.
[image]
Can someone help me how to proceed further.

Comment: Can somebody throw light on this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference please see the following blog, might help you resolve the problem for real device.
http://engineering.naukri.com/2016/04/android-wearsmartwatch-app-got-automated-naukri/

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments.